# Error on getErrorCodeName() in android code using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How to rectify the error "The method getErrorCodeName() is undefined for the type MulticastResult" ? I used following code

```
           MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, androidTargets, 1);

            if (result.getResults() != null) {
                int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                    // same device has more than on registration ID: update database
                }
            } else {
                int error = result.getFailure();
                System.out.println("Broadcast failure: " + error);
                String error_code_name = result.getErrorCodeName(); //Error is Here
                if (error_code_name.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
                       // application has been removed from device - unregister database or remove from database
                     }
            }
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
 result.getResults().get(0).getErrorCodeName();
```

or something like:

```
for(Result r : result.getResults()){ 
     if (Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED.equals(r)) {
           // application has been removed from device - unregister database or remove from database
     }   
}
```

API docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/MulticastResult.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/Result.html